# How to close all background processes in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have something like:

```
cd project && python manage.py runserver &
cd utilities && ./coffee_auto_compiler.py
```

And I want both of them to close on <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (or some other command). How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT**:
I tried using `jobs -x kill` and ``` kill ``jobs -p ``` , but it doesn't seem to kill what I need. Here is what I mean:

```
moon      8119  0.0  0.0   7556  3008 pts/0    S    13:17   0:00 /bin/bash
moon      8120  6.8  0.4  24568 18928 pts/0    S    13:17   0:00 python manage.py runserver
```

`jobs -p` give me just process 8119, but I also need to close 8120, since it's the thing that the first command opened.

*If it helps, the commands are actually in a Makefile, and I want it to run two daemons at the same time (and somehow close them at the same time). And yes, I'm using ubuntu, with bash*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way? since i dont know which distro you are using, ill assume its ubuntu. system>preferences>keyboard shortcuts. click add, name it, paste in your commands like this: "command1","command2" click add. click on the new shortcut, set shortcut key.

If that doesnt work for some reason, create a launcher with the commands, make sure it does what you want, and then use the above instructions to bind the launcher to the shortcut.

Comment: assuming you dont know how to kill a process, its basically like kill "process name"

Comment: I do know how to kill a process, but I want to make it as easy as Ctrl-C

Comment: which version of linux are you running? I dont want to sound irritated, but i just gave you the answer on a version of linux, and i could probably custom tailor the solution if i knew which version you were using. Or, you missed the answer. one of the two.

Comment: @Jason sorry about that, I modified the question.

Comment: I added more to my answer im thinking it should do what you want. if i need to clarify a step, i wont be mad ha ha.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru:  A wise man once said ["You can't always get what you want."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can%27t_Always_Get_What_You_Want)  :-)  I don't know of any way to make it as simple as Ctrl-C to kill multiple background jobs; using either the kill or jobs command is as good as you'll be able to do, I believe.

Comment: Why cant he bind these two commands to a launcher? There are many ways to do this, binding the commands to a launcher, or letting ubuntu do it for you are the simplest. as long as what he wants to kill is specified.

Answer (score 1):

To kill all background the jobs running under the Korn shell (ksh) or Bourne-again shell (bash), enter:

```
kill `jobs -p`
```

In bash, you may also use the following variant:

```
jobs -x kill
```

<sup>[source](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aegh.html)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

pstree

and then kill the root process using kill or pskill
these command might not be available in your distro

Comment: just read the extra info, well my other suggestion is to make a script and call the daemon from this script, killing the script process should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If your enclose your commands in backticks:

```
`cd project && python manage.py runserver` &
`cd utilities && ./coffee_auto_compiler.py` &
```

and run it with interactive ***bash session*** you would be able to kill them all with the only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

But you would not be able use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal and simultaneously not to kill all "backticked" commands that were being run from this terminal.