# Kill background processes started by bash script

Tags: macos, terminal, kill

I'd like to run the CoffeeScript and the Sass compilers in the background, and be able to kill them both at once. I have a bash script `start`, like this:

```
coffee --watch -o assets/ -c src/ &
sass --watch src:assets &
```

When started from a script file, they don't appear in the jobs list, so I can't kill them with:

```
kill `jobs -p`
```

as suggested in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/228911/how-to-close-all-background-processes-in-unix) post. They do appear in the `ps` output as being attached to my tty.

What is a good way to kill the processes started by my `start` script?

My aim is to start the compilers with `./start` and kill them with a `./stop` script. I'm using OSX Lion.

**Edit:** Based on grawity's answer, now I'm using:

```
coffee --watch -o assets/ -c src/ &
coffeepid=$!
sass --watch src:assets
kill $coffeepid
```

The Sass compiler complains if it is stopped using `kill`, so I'm stopping it with Ctrl-C then killing the background CoffeeScript compiler.

Comment: FWIW, pressing Ctrl-C is equivalent to `kill -INT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using MacOS X.  The system *comes with* a way to run user daemon processes, starting and stopping them as desired.  (The proper name for them in MacOS is *user agents*.)  [It's `launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), and the interface to it is [`launchctl`](http://developer.apple.com./library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).  Do this once per login session (modifying the pathnames for your compilers into absolute form as appropriate):

```
 launchctl submit -l com.example.coffee -- ${BINDIR}/coffee --watch -o assets/ -c src/
 launchctl submit -l com.example.sass -- ${BINDIR}/sass --watch src:assets
```

And in your start/stop scripts:

```
 launchctl start com.example.coffee
 launchctl start com.example.sass
 launchctl stop com.example.coffee
 launchctl stop com.example.sass
```

No [horrible accident-prone pid files](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotCreatePIDFiles).  No grep mismatches in the process table.  No muss.  No fuss.

Of course you can get creative with a property list, and adding it to your  `Library/LaunchAgents` directory, if you like — a simple property list file is not hard to knock together.  But `launchctl submit` is there for nonce user agents like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about launchd. I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score -2):

filter out the PID from ps and then feed it to kill (killing ping in this example):

```
ps -A | grep ping | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: -1 because of a *very* unreliable pipeline.

Comment: And another -1 because it's overly complicated and indirect.